# using a Custom Post Type in wordpress plugin e-commerce

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I'm building an e-commerce site, which got two types of "products". Before adding a plugin for the payment management I've already built two custom post types for my products (with [cmb2](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/))

The problem is that I don't find a way to import my custom post types in a e-commerce plugin (like woocommerce for example). Seems impossible to find a step-by-step guide to implement a solution for this problem. The only thing which I've found it's a not free [plugin](http://reigelgallarde.me/product/woocommerce-woorei-cpt/).

I've already tried the [basic guide](http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/how-to-add-custom-post-type-to-woocommerce/) from the same author of the not free plugin, which consist in modify the functions.php file adding this snippet:

```
<?php
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','reigel_woocommerce_get_price',20,2);
function reigel_woocommerce_get_price($price,$post){
    if ($post->post->post_type === 'post')
        $price = get_post_meta($post->id, "price", true);
    return $price;
}
```

where "price" `in get_post_meta` is the name of my meta price, and 'post' is my custom post type.
At the end we need to add this form in the custom post type content:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="add-to-cart" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" />
        <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1"  />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
 </form>
```

The guide says that after this procedure my "custom product" will be added in the basket, but it's not my case. Any Idea why? Maybe the woocommerce plugin is changed and this workaround doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use categories for your products instead of custom post types (for exmaple: books, furniture, movies...). divide your products to the relevant category so you'd stay inline with WooCommerece's basic structure.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot do this, because I got a specific layout confirmed by the customer for the custom products. I cannot change it using another template (like the one used by woocommerce, which by the way it's very complex to modify without doing something wrong)